# Making git-buildpackage work with big tarballs

Tags: debian, packaging

When using [git-buildpackage](http://honk.sigxcpu.org/projects/git-buildpackage/manual-html/), there are two ways to get upstream sources:

1. retrieving them from an upstream branch; or
2. importing release tarballs into the repository.

My team is looking into packaging Oracle Java. We develop our package in git and would like to use gbp. Obviously, option (1) is out of the question, since sources are not available. But option (2) is not feasible either, since it would mean importing huge (200MB+) archives into git.

Since Debian's policy is against proprietary software, you don't find much documentation about this use case out there. Still, there must be a way.

dpkg-buildpackage is not enough either, since [`get-orig-sources` is deprecated](https://wiki.debian.org/onlyjob/get-orig-source). Now you're expected to use either uscan and `debian/watch` or git-buildpackage.

Comment: Just found out [git-buildpackage supports a `--uscan` option](https://honk.sigxcpu.org/projects/git-buildpackage/manual-html/gbp.import.new.upstream.html). It imports it into the repository, so it's as inappropriate as the other options, but might be useful for automated building of the package.

Answer (score 1):

#### There is no problem with `git buildpackage` and huge files.

What makes you think there is?
Which problems do you expect when importing "huge" tarballs into your git repository?
Are they related to `gbp`? Or is it just the way `git` handles large binary blobs (which is really an entirely different matter).
You might want to checkout `git-lfs` or similar, if you are truly concerned about large repository sizes.

#### Since Debian's policy is against proprietary software, you don't find much documentation about this use case out there.

Which use case?
Having huge release tarballs is not something unique to proprietary software.
(Think games... there *are* FLOSS games that come with zillions of data).

So your options are:
- either include the large upstream tarballs
- or repack them to throw away the stuff you don't need (e.g. pre-compiled binaries for W32, W64 and BeOS are usually useless in he context of a Debian package, but can blow up packaging sizes enormously). The standard tool for fetching upstream tarballs (`uscan`) includes mechanism to automatically remove files when importing a new upstream release.

#### get-orig-source is deprecated

So what? The article you reference clearly states that it's "existence in debian/rules file is absolutely fine".
Also, the issue of `git-orig-source` vs `uscan` is orthogonal to the problem you are describing.
Both are means to fetch the sources from a remote location, to start packaging a new release.
**Neither** is there to be used during the build-process to get the otherwise-missing upstream sources (you might be confused because the `get-orig-source` is a Makefile target. But this target is never actually called except manually by humans who want to fetch the sources).

#### dpkg-buildpackage is not enough either

Why not?
If you have the orig-tarball in a place where dpkg-buildpackage can find it, you can certainly use it.

`gbp` is a very nice tool for an integrated workflow that keeps Debian packaging (everything in `/debian`) and upstream snapshots in a single repository.

This might not necessarily be the workflow you desire (e.g. because you explicitly do not want to include upstream sources in your packaging repository).

In this case, `gbp` might not be the right tool for you.

Luckily there's absolutely nothing that forces you to use this tool. Feel free to use `git-dpm`, `dpkg-buildpackage`, or roll your own package manually without any helpers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is indeed the way git itself handles large files. Git LFS is not available in our case, as we use CodeCommit. There's nothing to throw away in Oracle's archives. And, indeed, there are FLOSS packages with huge upstream tarballs, but I doubt those tarballs are included in the git repos where the packages themselves are developed! We need something like buildd on AWS, and fetching upstream archives as part of that automated process would be nice.